# Multiple quotes in command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to execute command with multiple quotes, but seems problematic:

```
sudo su - postgres -c 'psql -U postgres -c "alter user postgres with password 'dummy';"'
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "dummy"
LINE 1: alter user postgres with password dummy;
                                          ^
```

If i dot the same command in two step, no problems:

```
sudo su - postgres                                                                      
postgres@courgette:~$ psql -U postgres -c "alter user postgres with password 'dummy';"
ALTER ROLE
```

How correctly quote "dummy" in one line first exemple ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per [the *Bash Reference Manual*, §3.1.2.2 "Single Quotes"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes):

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘`'`’) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

So, you have three reasonable options:

- you can exit the single-quoted bit just long enough to add a double-quoted single-quote:

  ```
  sudo su - postgres -c 'psql -U postgres -c "alter user postgres with password '"'"'dummy'"'"';"'
  ```
- you can use double-quotes `"..."`, in which case you have to escape any internal double-quotes:

  ```
  sudo su - postgres -c "psql -U postgres -c \"alter user postgres with password 'dummy';\""
  ```
- you can use `$'...'` (which differs from both `'...`' and `"..."` in that it supports a wide variety of C-style escape sequences), in which case you have to escape any internal single-quotes:

  ```
  sudo su - postgres -c $'psql -U postgres -c "alter user postgres with password \'dummy\';"'
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of running `su` with `sudo`, just run `psql` directly. This eliminates one level of quotes, as well as the need to specify the user with the `-U` option:

```
sudo -u postgres psql "alter user postgres with password 'dummy';"
```

If you can't do that for whatever reason, use a here document to eliminate a level of quotes:

```
sudo su - postgres -U postgres <<EOF
alter user postgres with password 'dummy'
EOF
```

Comment: +1. Good points both. Note that if you have permission to `sudo` as `root`, but not as an arbitrary user, you can write `sudo sudo -u postgres` to `sudo` as `root` and have `root` `sudo` as `postgres` (since `root` can always `sudo` as anyone).

Comment: You can probably also just edit `/etc/sudoers` to give yourself permission to  `sudo` as an arbitrary user ;)

Comment: At my work, sudoers permissions are managed centrally, and are tied to all kinds of auditing stuff. I'm pretty sure that manually editing them on a box would get me a talking-to. But `sudo sudo -u ...` is fine, because it doesn't bypass the auditing. (Of course, at my work, `sudo su ...` is right out, since the contents of the `su` session can't be audited. So the OP is probably in a different sort of environment.)